# Why LINQ Count() returning multiple rows instead one?

Tags: sql, linq, count, rows

I would like to translate the following SQL into LINQ:

```
    select  count(p.ID) as NumPosts,
            count(t.Trustee_ID)as TrusteePost,
            count(pat.ID)as PatientPost,
            count(s.ID) as SpecialistPost
           from [dbo].[Posts] as p 
    left join [dbo].[Trusteehips] as t
    on  p.Autor_ID = t.Trustee_ID
    left join [dbo].[Patients] as pat
    on  p.Autor_ID = pat.ID 
    left join [dbo].[Specialists] as s
    on  p.Autor_ID = s.ID
    where p.Deleted = 0
```

I I've tried this:

```
var res = from p in context.Posts
                      join t in context.Trusteeships
                      on p.Autor.ID equals t.Trustee.ID into tGroup
                      join pat in context.Patients
                      on p.Autor.ID equals pat.ID into patGroup
                      join s in context.Specialists
                      on p.Autor.ID equals s.ID into sGroup
                      select new NumUserPosts
                      {
                          //CountAllPosts = ?
                          TrusteePost = tGroup.Count(),
                          PatientPost = patGroup.Count(),
                          SpecialistPost = sGroup.Count()
                      };
```

But result is this:

```
1 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 1
0 1 0

and etc.
```

I expect result

```
TrusteePost    PatientPost   SpecialistPost
    1000         2000            3000
```

Why when i try to count group return this result?
SQL query is correct. I would like to translate into LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing group joins instead of left outer joins (see [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)).

A left outer join looks more like:

```
var res = from p in context.Posts
              join t in context.Trusteeships
                  on p.Autor.ID equals t.Trustee.ID into tGroup
                  from tJoin in tGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join pat in context.Patients
                  on p.Autor.ID equals pat.ID into patGroup
                  from patJoin in patGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join s in context.Specialists
                  on p.Autor.ID equals s.ID into sGroup
                  from sJoin in sGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select ...
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that Linq can create a query to count elements in each column.

If you don't mind using multiple queries, you could count each separately, for example:

```
var trusteePost = (from p in context.Posts 
                   join t in context.Trusteeships on p.Autor.ID equals t.Trustee.ID
                   select t).Count()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but trow me exception in View

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Count()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

 @foreach (var item in Model)

I try with ToList(), but didnt work.

Comment: After trying it out, it seems like Linq doesn't support counting in that way (as @Gert Arnold said below), so I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, jjj !
i use separate queries  and this work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The query returns 0 or 1 records per joined `Trustee`, etc. because you outer join by the unique primary key. So a `join into` (which is a `GroupJoin` in fluent syntax) produces a group of 0 or 1 records. If you run the generated SQL query and view the raw query result you'd probably understand better what's going on.

The problem is, there is no LINQ equivalent for `count(t.Trustee_ID)`, etc. Therefore it's impossible to do what you want in one query without "hacking".

Hacking it into one query could be done like so:

```cs
(from p in context.Posts.Take(1)
select new 
{
  TrusteePost = context.Posts
                  .Count(p1 => context.Trusteeships.Any(x => x.ID == p1.Autor.ID)),
  PatientPost = context.Posts
                  .Count(p2 => context.Patients.Any(x => x.ID == p2.Autor.ID)),
  SpecialistPost = context.Posts
                     .Count(p3 => context.Specialists.Any(x => x.ID == p3.Autor.ID))
})
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new NumUserPosts
{
  CountAllPosts = x.TrusteePost + x.PatientPost + x.SpecialistPost,
  x.TrusteePost,
  x.PatientPost,
  x.SpecialistPost
}
```

The SQL query will be much more elaborate than the original SQL (for example, it involves cross joins), but it will probably still perform pretty well. `AsEnumerable` prevents the second part from being executed as SQL, which would bloat the SQL statement even more. It simply runs in memory.

I consider this a hack because the first part, `context.Posts.Take(1)` doesn't really have any meaning, it's only there to serve as a wrapper for the three separate queries. It's poor man's query packaging.

Comment: Thank you!!! Very interesting answer, but show me 3 errors:

A local variable named 'p' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'p', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

Maybe i do something wrong.
Thank you for answer once again !!!

Comment: This should fix it :)